# How can I correctly mock opensearch indices.exist with jest

Tags: amazon-web-services, jestjs, amazon-opensearch

I am using OpenSearch client and I would like to test the `indices.exists`, however when I run jest test, I get the error `openSearchClient.indices.exists is not a function`. How can I access the `exists` property using jest?
I understand the below code is trying to access `mockOpenSearchClient.indices().exists()` but I've looked at the documentation but can't seem to figure out how to make it mock `mockOpenSearchClient.indices.exists()`,
below is my mock setup

```
const mockOpenSearchClient = {
indices: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        exists: jest.fn((obj, cb) => {
          return cb("", existsResp);
        }),
      };
    }),
} as unknown as Client;
```

After following the jest [documentation and example here](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#complete-example) I was able to modify my setup to the below code but still no success,

```
const mockOpenSearchClient = {
    indices: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        exists: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: true,
          };
        }),
      };
    }),
  } as unknown as Client;
```

If I log mockOpenSearchClient this is what I get back

```
openSearchClient {
      indices: [Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        withImplementation: [Function: bound withImplementation],
        mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
        getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    }
```

How do I successfully access the `mockOpenSearchClient.indices.exists` method?

Comment: `indices` isn't a method, `exists` is a property of it not a property of its return value. But this is a really good example of why you shouldn't mock what you don't own - that's a very complicated test double, and putting your own facade over that API would be easier to mock _and_ decouple the rest of your code from the dependency.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I'm not that versed with jest mocking, I've edited the question and added additional info. What I am looking for is a way to access `mockOpenSearchClient.indices.exists()` as I understand my current approach is looking for `mockOpenSearchClient.indices().exists()`

Comment: Your test double of indices is a function, `jest.fn()`, when the real thing is an object. So change the test double - **at minimum** a test double needs to have an API compatible with what it's supposed to replace. Or, again, implement a facade to protect the rest of your code from the third party API, then create a (much simpler) test double _of the facade_ to test against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was finally able to mock it by simply constructing an object and then mocking the resolved value to the function:

```
const mockOpenSearchClient = {
   indices: {
     exists: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(existsResp);
     get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(getResp);
   }
} as unknown as Client;
```